# temporarily removing an image from python

Tags: python, pygame

I want an object to not render after the player touches it.

```
if dollary + dollar_width > y:
        if dollary < y + smiley_height:
            if dollarx > x and dollarx < x + smiley_width or dollarx + dollar_width > x and dollarx + dollar_width < x + smiley_width:
                points += 1
```

This gives the player(y and x) points when dollar(dollary and dollarx) and player overlap, but I want the dollar to dissapear as soon as the player touches it.

I tried:

```
os.remove("file.gif")
```

It removed the actual file rather than not render it.

Edit: Here's my game loop:

```
def game_loop():

x = (display_width * 0.5 - (smiley_width/2))
y = (display_height * 0.8)

x_change = 0

thing_width = 100
thing_height = 100
thing_startx = random.randrange(0, (display_width - thing_width))
thing_starty = -600
thing_speed = 3

dollarx = thing_startx
dollary = thing_starty - 90
dollar_height = 87
dollar_width = 82

dodged = 0
points = 0

gameExit = False

while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0

    x += x_change

    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    #things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color)
    things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, red)
    thing_starty += thing_speed

    dollar(dollarx,dollary)
    dollary += thing_speed
    smiley (x,y)
    things_dodged(dodged)
    score(points)

    if x > display_width - smiley_width or x < 0:
        die()

    if dollary > display_height:
        thing_speed += 1
        thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
        thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
        dollarx = thing_startx
        dollary = thing_starty - 90
        dodged += 1
        thing_width += (dodged * 0.9)

    if y + smiley_height > thing_starty:
        if y < thing_starty + thing_height:
            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + smiley_width > thing_startx and x + smiley_width < thing_startx + thing_width:
                die()

    if dollary + dollar_width > y:
        if dollary < y + smiley_height:
            if dollarx > x and dollarx < x + smiley_width or dollarx + dollar_width > x and dollarx + dollar_width < x + smiley_width:
                points += 1

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

It's a bit messy but I'm very new to this, so any pointers are welcome

Comment: Looking at the os.remove call docs, the call is doing what it is supposed to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_remove.htm. You need a way to hide the display in python and pygame, not remove the actual file. Please refer to the documentation https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pygame/latest/pygame.pdf to find a better way to hide the object.

Comment: You would need to stop drawing it in the event loop.  Show us your event loop

Comment: I copied in my game loop

Answer (score 0):

You should have a display loop. Once a frame, you clear the screen, then blit all your images to it. Simply do not blit this image to the screen on the next frame.